# R error "object ‘get()’ not found" when trying to save() an object to disk

Tags: r

When I use get(myDataFrame) to get a data frame by its name, it comes up with an error like so

```
    > head(myData, 2)
           myData.Open myData.High myData.Low myData.Close myData.Volume myData.Adjusted
2012-05-01    21.29515    21.52864   21.25490     21.52864         12600        21.52864
2012-05-02    21.72991    22.01975   21.65745     22.01975         15100        22.01975

myDataFrame -> "myData"
    save(get(myDataFrame), file = paste("C:\\Users\\Admin\\Documents\\trading\\R\\Data\\Yahoo\\", myDataFrame, "_daily.R", sep=""))

Error in save(get(myDataFrame), file = paste("C:\\Users\\Admin\\Documents\\trading\\R\\Data\\Yahoo\\",  : 
  object ‘get(myDataFrame)’ not found
```

Note: the

Comment: Thanks, Yes i know that works but i have a vector with a list of names in it, that i need to loop though and save all objects

Comment: `save(list = ...)`

Comment: yes thanks that worked!

Comment: I still don't understand why get("someDataFrame") works normally, but not inside the save function?? is this just R?